# Need Help creating Drupal content type with form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

I am fairly new to Drupal 7.9 and still trying to get a hang of it. Understandably it has a learning curve which I am trying to scale at the moment.

My challenge here is to basically create a page that has some backend processing to it. The front page consists of form elements (mostly textboxes) arranged in a tabular format.

A little bit of exploring and I reckoned I might need to create a kind of content type and then add content. But I got nowhere with this.

Then I discovered the webform module that lets me create form elements and provides a bunch of operations. But it doesn't necessarily allow me to display my form elements in tabular format.

So before exploring on my own again, I felt it would be right to ask questions from you guys.

Anybody with any leads on this ?

Thanks much !!!

Parijat

Answer (score 0):

Webform is not a display engine and you will get nowhere fast with that approach! CCK is a display engine, not a processing engine either. If you want to add some kind of processing between the input and display phases you will need to find a module that does what you want (www.drupalmodules.com), or write one yourself...